# how to find $\lim_{\large x \to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\tan^{3}\left(x\right)-3\tan\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

how to find

> $$\lim_{\large x \to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\tan^{3}\left(x\right)-3\tan\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}$$ without L'hopital or taylor/Laurent series

I tried but did not get any answer:

$$\frac{\tan^{2}\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)-3\tan\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}=\frac{2\left(\sin^{3}\left(x\right)-3\sin\left(x\right)\cos^{2}\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos^{3}\left(x\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}=\frac{2\left(\sin^{3}\left(x\right)-3\left(\sin\left(x\right)\left(1-\sin^{2}\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)}{\cos^{3}\left(x\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}=\frac{2}{1}\frac{-3\left(\sin(x)-\sin^{2}\left(x\right)\right)+\sin^{3}\left(x\right)}{\left(1-\sin^{2}\left(x\right)\right)(\cos(x))\left(\sqrt{3}\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{\large x \to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\tan^{3}\left(x\right)-3\tan\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}=$$

$$\lim_{\large x \to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{\tan x (\tan x - \sqrt 3)(\tan x +\sqrt 3)}{\cos x \cos (\pi /6)-\sin x \sin (\pi /6)}=$$

$$\lim_{\large x \to \frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{(2\sec x)\tan x (\tan x - \sqrt 3)(\tan x +\sqrt 3)}{\sqrt 3 - \tan x}=-24$$

Comment: You've rewritten $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}\cos x-\sin x}$ as $\frac{2\color{red}{\cos x}}{\sqrt{3}-\tan x}$ when it should be $\frac{2\color{limegreen}{\sec x}}{\sqrt{3}-\tan x}$, so the correct answer is $-2\sec\frac{\pi}{3}\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\left(\tan\frac{\pi}{3}+\sqrt{3}\right)=-4\sqrt{3}(2\sqrt{3})=-24$.

Comment: @J.G.  Thanks for the comment.  I have corrected my error.

Comment: interesting answer,@Mohammad Riazi -Kermani are you from Iran?if yes I am too (just curious)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\tan^3 x-3\tan x}{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}
&=\tan(x)\cdot\frac{\tan^2 x-3}{\cos x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-\sin x\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{6}\right)},\quad\quad x\neq \frac{\pi}{3}
\\
&=\frac{2\sin x}{\cos^{3} x}\cdot\frac{\sin x^{2}-3\cos x^{2}}{\sqrt{3}\cos x-\sin x}\quad\quad\text{(1)}
\\
&=\frac{2\sin x}{\cos^{3} x}\cdot\frac{\left(\sin x^{2}-3\cos x^{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x\right)}{\left(\sqrt{3}\cos x-\sin x\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x\right)}
\\
&=-\frac{2\sin x}{\cos^{3} x}\cdot\frac{4\cos^{2} x-1}{4\cos^{2} x-1}\cdot\left(\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x\right)\quad\quad\text{(2)}
\end{aligned}$$

Equation $(1)$ uses $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $(2)$ uses $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$. Hence, by substitution, the limit is $-24$.

Comment: very interesting +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x-\pi/3$, so we are to compute
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan^{3}(y+\pi/3)-3\tan(y+\pi/3)}{\cos(y+\pi/2)}.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\tan^{3}(y+\pi/3)-3\tan(y+\pi/3)&=\tan(3(y+\pi/3))(3\tan^{2}(y+\pi/3)-1)\\
&=(\tan(3y))(3\tan^{2}(y+\pi/3)-1),
\end{align*}
and the term reduces to 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(\tan(3y))(3\tan^{2}(y+\pi/3)-1)}{-\sin y}.
\end{align*}
But 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan 3y}{\sin y}=3\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin 3y}{3y}\dfrac{1}{\cos 3y}\dfrac{y}{\sin y}=3.
\end{align*}